# Can read mail on iPhone but not on computer

Tags: iphone, password, hotmail

I can check mail on my Phone because the password was inputted when set up.  After a while I forgot it and cannot check mail on my computer!  I tried to retrieve it by using the "I forgot ..," but after many tries, not successful.  How can I find out the password that I "saved" in my iPhone ?

Comment: There's no way you can read it as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Use [iforgot](https://iforgot.apple.com/) password technique to set a new password.